# The rules of using 'the' article

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-articles

This short example covers most of my questions:

> **The** proposed methods are capable of keeping **the** growth of constraint violation errors associated with the calculation of
> gradient at a minimum rate.

Articles in bold are the ones that I am sure are ok. There are, however, other cases that I am not so sure and even don't understand what is the reason for the article to stand (or not to stand) there. Here are my questions:

1. Is it `the` calculation of gradient, calculation of `the` gradient, or `the` calculation of `the` gradient?

   The last option feels the safest to me, however, the text becomes very cluttered with these articles, which, for me, looks pretty bad. If some other case is correct, why is that in particular?
2. Why there is no `the` before `constraint violation errors`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The" is a definite article, and is generally taken to mean a *particular instance* of something.

1. One would generally only speak of "calculation of gradient" if that were a phrase of art. For instance: "This is a calculation of gradient problem."

   Most likely the proper phrase is "The calculation of the gradient". Leaving out the second "the" would sound awkward.
2. In the phrase "keeping the growth of constraint violation errors", we aren't talking about errors which have an antecedent in this conversation, but some possible future errors. Having a "the" there would imply there was a particular, seen before, set of errors. Consider the difference between "The horses like apples" in a conversation regarding a pair of animals owned by the writer, as compared to "Horses like apples", a statement made by a trainer of horses dispensing wisdom on treats for horses in general.